# A logical question

Tags: logic

A logical question from LSAT:

> Authorities concerned with mass transport in metropolitan cities are
>   struggling with deficits. Commuters complain about delays and
>   breakdowns, cuts in service, and fares higher than they are accustomed
>   to paying. For all these reasons and because the price of fuel is
>   still not prohibitive, the number of commuters using public
>   transportation has fallen, adding to the deficits.
>
> Which among the following statements about the relationship between
>   the number of commuters using public transportation and the price of
>   fuel is best supported by the above passage?
>
> A. With the rise in the price of fuel, there is a rise in the number
>   of commuters using public transportation.
>
> B.    Even if the price of fuel rises, the number of commuters using
>   public transportation will continue to decline.
>
> C.    The number of commuters using public transportation will rise,
>   if the price of fuel rises to a prohibitive level.
>
> D.    Most of the commuters using public transportation do not use
>   fuel, therefore fluctuations in the price of fuel is unlikely to
>   affect the number of commuters using public transportation.
>
> E.    The price of fuel is always low enough to make private
>   transportation cheaper than public transportation; therefore
>   fluctuations in the price of fuel is unlikely to affect the number of
>   commuters using public transportation.
>
> Ans : C

I was wondering why C is correct? Let me use the following notations:

(a) delays and breakdowns,

(b) cuts in service,

(c) fares higher than they are accustomed to paying.

(d) the price of fuel is still not prohibitive,

(e) the number of commuters using public transportation has fallen

The choice C says that ~(d) => ~(e), but I only find from the passage that (a) + (b) + (c) + (d) => (e). Why does C say that (d) a necessary condition for (e)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe lawyers don't do formal logic.

The important word here is "because". This means it's not just an implication in the mathematical/logical sense, but a case of causation.  Other things being equal, if the cause of $(e)$ is removed we would expect $(e)$ to also be removed.

Comment: Thanks! I think lawyers do formal logic. I don't quite understand the difference between the two meanings of "because". If "because A, B", is A a necessary condition for B in case of causation?

Comment: No, $B$ could have many different possible causes. $A$ might be neither a necessary condition nor a sufficient condition.  E.g. "he died because he was stabbed".  Being stabbed is not a necessary condition (he might have been shot instead of stabbed), and not a sufficient condition (he might have survived the stabbing).

Comment: So for "because A, B": in case of causation, A may be neither necessary nor sufficient for B; in case of mathematics/logics, A is a sufficient for B?